# Belief propagation on MRF with complex cliques

Tags: machine-learning, graph-theory

Is there a belief propagation algorithm for exact inference on a MRF with complex clique structures (i.e. ones involving more than 2 neighbours)?

For MRF's with cliques that only involve pairwise interaction, you could just search out far enough and cluster to form an acyclic graph and run the usual BP.  With more complex cliques, this seems impossible to me as clustering might involve cutting through a clique with multiple members on either side.  Is there a workaround for this?  Perhaps some clever conditioning arguments?

Answer (score 2):

You can take your graph and form a junction tree, I can't find a good link but either Michael Jordan's text or Daphne Koller's would have pseudo code.

Comment: I am already using junction tree - I am trying to figure out if there is some way to do this when I can't guarantee a tree of bipartite components.

Comment: So you can always use junction tree, the only problem is the cost scales exponentially in the size of the largest clique. This is a big problem with graphs that have "loops", in which case there are no efficient solutions and you have to approximate.  The standard methods would be loopy belief propagation, variational bayes, expectation propagation, or Monte Carlo methods (usually Gibbs sampling)

Answer (score 1):

You have many options!

1. You can form Junction Tree of your tree and do the conventional Belief Popagation on the resulting graph. (See chapter )
2. Choose one of the (loopy)BP family algorithms, based on your concern for time or complexity (This is a big family!).

See [1] for a complete list of BP family inferences in MRFs.

[1] http://www.nowozin.net/sebastian/papers/kappes2013energyminimization.pdf